# How to enable dynamic bit rate switching in Amazon S3 Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-s3, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront

I am using JWPlayer with RTMP streaming for a video with several bitrate quality levels.

In the JWPlayer configuration you specify the qualities [like this](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16012/setting-up-rtmp-dynamic-streaming) :

```
'levels': [
          { bitrate:"2920", width:"1920", file:"videos/sintel-1920.mp4" },
          { bitrate:"2080", width:"1280", file:"videos/sintel-1280.mp4" },
          { bitrate:"2080", width:"720", file:"videos/sintel-720.mp4" },
          { bitrate:"650", width:"480", file:"videos/sintel-480.mp4" },
          { bitrate:"420", width:"320", file:"videos/sintel-320.mp4" }
       ]
```

I thought this was all I had to do but then I came across the following on [Amazon's Cloudfront page](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/):

> Amazon CloudFront lets you create
>   “streaming distributions” to deliver
>   your rich media content in a different
>   way than other Amazon CloudFront
>   distributions.... Amazon CloudFront
>   uses Adobe’s Flash® Media Server to
>   power its streaming distributions.....
>
> ..... You can also **configure your
>   streaming distributions to use dynamic
>   bit-rate streaming.** When enabled,
>   this feature lets you store multiple
>   copies of the same video, each encoded
>   at different quality levels. Your
>   distribution will then automatically
>   adjust the quality of your video based
>   on the speed of the end user’s
>   internet connection.

This implies that in Amazon S3 there are both `streaming distributions` and a separate configuration for `dynamic bit-rate streaming distributions`. Is this correct?

Does this mean I have to enable a feature in Amazon to get the best dynamic switching - or will JWPlayer switch by itself just fine? I'm not clear if this is a separate sever side function that will work better than JWPlayer - or whether it works in conjunction with it.

Any further information on this?

Comment: don't find a reference to the word 'dynamic' in the API documentation once http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/CF/20101101/cf_api_20101101.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These documents are always confusing.  You do not need to bother, JW player takes care of this, but you do have to upload those different video formats to your streaming enabled bucket, of course.