# Jwplayer player 6 for all device with onlick change src url variables

Tags: javascript, android, html, jwplayer

I would like to setup jwplayer with various streaming protocols, for flash/pc/mac and for html5 player for hls capable-device and at the end with a fallback link that that for old android and blackberyy device. That's working fine with a static code. But I would like to change dynamically the player scr onclick for different streaming quality.

I have this script (in the header also) to change dynamically the player source onclick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function changeVideo(filename1,filename2,filename3) {
         jwplayer("myplayer").setup({
          autostart: true,
           autoplay: true,
           width: 640,
           height: 360,
           aspectratio: "16:9"
           playlist: [{
            image: "/images/poster.jpg",
            sources: [{
              file: filenam1
              },{
              file: filenam2
            },{
              file: filenam3,
            }]
          }],
           primary: "flash"
        });
        jwplayer('myplayer').load();
    }
         </script>
```

filaname1, filename2, filename3 are variables which listen to the html/js onchange fonction which also has 3 links separated with a "," .
And in the body I have this:

```
<div id="myplayer">Loading the player...</div>
  //this is the default static player setup which is working fine
   <script>
    jwplayer("myplayer").setup({
    aboutlink: "http://mywebsite.com",
    autostart: true,
    width: 768,
    height: 432,
    aspectratio: "16:9",
      playlist: [{
        image: "/images/poster.jpg",
        sources: [{
          file: "rtmp://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname"
          },{
          file: "http://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname/playlist.m3u8"
        },{
          file: "rtsp://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname"
        }]
      }],
      primary: "flash"
    });
</script>
```

// here are the quality links to change dynamically onlick, with three links

```
<p><a class="button" href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript:changeVideo('rtmp://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname1,http://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname1/playlist.m3u8,rtsp://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname1');">Low Quality</a> 

<a class="button" href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript:changeVideo('rtmp://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname2,http://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname2/playlist.m3u8,rtsp://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname2');">SD Quality</a> 

<a class="button" href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript:changeVideo('rtmp://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname3,http://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname3/playlist.m3u8,rtsp://servername-or-ip:1935/appname/streamname3');">HD Quality</a> 
</p>
```

If there someone to help? that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is this running? Do you have an example?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an online example. I'm developing it locally. Its for a customer. I don't have any owned web server right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable dynamic bit rate switching in Amazon S3 Cloudfront?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794971/how-to-enable-dynamic-bit-rate-switching-in-amazon-s3-cloudfront)